# how to edit text inside multiple draggables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to know how I can edit text inside draggable without editing other draggables this is my code I can add multiple draggbales with text on them but I want to edit individual draggables without changing the other draggables if you need more info please ask

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  
 <script>var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
    /** Make div draggable **/
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'ui-widget-content',
        appendTo: '.container',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent',
            start: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
            }
        }
    });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
    $(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
    return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
    var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
    if (editingText.length)
    {
        editingText.hide();
        editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
    }
});

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.textContent = ko.observable('');
    self.init=function(){
        self.items([]);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.addNew = function() {
      self.items.push( self.textContent() );
      self.textContent('');
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
</script>

<script>

$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
    var thmb = this;
    var src  = this.src;
    $(thmb).parent('.thumbs').prev('.bottlesWrapper').find('img').fadeOut(400,function(){
        thmb.src = this.src;
        $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
    });
});








$("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.item').css("font-family", $(this).val());

});

$("#size").change(function() {
    $('.item').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});


$('.foo').click(function(){
 $('.item').css("color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
</script>
```

```css
<style>.item{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background:transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    display:block;
}

.edit_text
{
    display: none;
}

.fix_backround
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style><style>
.thumbs img{
  margin:3px;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
}</style>
<style>
.bottlesWrapper img{
  margin:3px;
  width:400px;
  float:left;
}</style>
<style>#main { border:1px solid #eee; margin:20px; width:410px; height:220px;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .transparent { background:transparent }
</style>

<style>.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
.yellow {
  background: #FAFF38;


}.black {
  background: #000000;
}

</style><style>   #mainTarget{
    width:30px; 
    height:20px; 
    position:relative;
    top:100px; 
    left:25%
}

.mainTarget{position:absolute; width:25px; height:25px;}

#target{
    position:absolute;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    background:url(http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/human-o2-icons-by-oliver-scholtz/png/128x128/actions/object-rotate-left.png) no-repeat top center #ffffff;
 background-size:100%;
    cursor:pointer; 
    z-index:1; 
    top:1; 
    right:1;    
}
</style>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
 
   
<div id="colour" >
  <div class="foo white" data-color="#FFFFFF"></div>
  <div class="foo black" data-color="#000000"></div>
  <div class="foo yellow" data-color="#FAFF38"></div>

</div>
    <select id="fs"> 
        <option value="Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
        <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
        <option value="AR Berkley">AR Berkley</option>
        <option value="AR Blanca">AR Blanca</option>
        <option value="AR Bonnie">AR Bonnie</option>
        <option value="AR Carter">AR Carter</option>
        <option value="AR Cena">AR Cena</option>
       
    </select>
    
    



 
 </form>
<textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append"></textarea>
<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>

<div class="container">
<div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
    <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
        <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I't working to me. I edit one draggable and it changes only it's text. Can you please explain better ?

Comment: just double click on the text you want to edit :) it's working as Nelson said!

Comment: Try adding another text using the same input text box you will see what I'm talking about I want to edit one at a time differently